# Express different paths but same logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

i have a route like this

```
router.post('/policy', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})
```

I want the same logic to be executed when `/role` is called what is the correct way to do this ? ( preferrably without copy pasting the same code )

I can think of this logic

```
router.post('/policy', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})

router.post('/role', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})
```

**Why am i naming the routes differently for same logic ?**

Because i want the back-end to be more read-able and specific to what task it is doing i.e adding policy OR role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for both route `/policy` and `/role`:

```
router.post(['/policy', '/role'], async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})
```